# jQuery applying two CSS classes, one is applying my formatting, one is not

Tags: jquery, css

Right off the bat here is my code so you can point out the ultra obvious mistake that I have been beating my head against my keyboard searching for:

CSS:

```
.li_hover { background-color: #add8e6; };
.li_selected { background-color: #add8e6; };
```

(relevant) JavaScript/jQuery:

```
//Change background color when hovering over element
$("li").hover(function(){
    console.log("hover");
    $(this).toggleClass("li_hover");
});

$("li").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");

    $(this).addClass("li_selected");
    //This isn't working, visually show element was selected

});
```

(relevant) HTML:

```
<div id="playerCountDiv">
Player Count:

<ul id="playerCountList">
    <li id="2Players" value="17"> 2 </li>
    <li id="3Players" value="18"> 3 </li>
    <li id="4Players" value="21"> 4 </li>
    <li id="5Players" value="25"> 5 </li>
    <li id="6Players" value="28"> 6 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I want to happen: when I hover over an li element, the background color changes. When I click it, it stays that color (or turns a different color, haven't decided for sure).

The hovering works as expected, and I have more JavaScript in the .click function that all runs. When I inspect the page, the li_selected class is in fact applied to each element when clicked, but the style doesn't actually change. My assumption is that something in the entire two lines of CSS I have written is causing the style to not apply, even though both classes apply correctly.

Interestingly, if I flip the two lines of CSS around, so that li_selected is on top, then neither one works at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra ";" in your CSS that break the styling. Everything looks fine otherwise. I have fixed them while editing your code example into a snippet.

This should work:

```css
.li_hover {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

.li_selected {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I knew it was something minor that I overlooked.

Comment: you shouldn't edit the original question to fix issue, you will simply make it irrelevant as there will be no more issue.

Answer (score -1):

When two CSS selectors are of the same strength, the latter rendered in the browser will be considered by the browser. You may need to adjust the CSS specificity:

Option 1: Adjust the [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```css
#playerCountList .li_hover { background-color: #add8e6;  }
```

Option 2: Use `!important`

```css
.li_hover { background-color: #add8e6 !important;  }
```

Option 3: Use only CSS to do the job:

```css
#playerCountList li:hover { background-color: #add8e6; }
```

Comment: Specificity is fine in the author case. It's two single classes and `li_selected` comes after `li_hover`.

Comment: You have the point. I did not notice the extra semicolon ;) If not the semicolon, the second potential problem could have been the specificity. Cheers!